# How to check if a unicode character is symbol or word?

Tags: c++, objective-c, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

In regular expression, we can use `\w` to figure out whether a character is a word or a symbol.

Here is a test using regular expression in Xcode.

[image: unicode]

As you see, it will find out all words in different languages correctly. So I am wondering how to implement this.

One of the way may be checking the unicode number in [unicode plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)). As an example, `0x30` to `0x39` are numbers so they are words. `0x02B0` to `0x02FF` are spacing modifier letters so they are symbols.

BUT, how can I figure out all other unicode numbers ? Or how regular expression implement this both in pure C++ or ObjC ?

Comment: There are several libraries that provide metadata about unicode characters. www.google.com is down the hall,  last door on your left.

Comment: If you need Unicode handling beyond reading, storing and printing strings, you should use a library like ICU. C++ just doesn't have any real Unicode support.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks for your answer. And I wonder how to implement this in ObjC. Is there a builtin library ?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about that language. Never used it.

Comment: Have you tried `iswalpha` and friends? (To implement `iswalpha` you would need a database of all characters of the locale, but this database is normally provided by the locale).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I did google it before asking this. ICU may be a solution. Now I wonder whether a builtin library in ObjC and how to re-implement it by myself (for studying).

Comment: @n.m. `iswalphe` can only figure out alpha, digit and something like them. But it's useless for unicode char like Chinese, Japanese and so on.

Comment: Have you tried? https://ideone.com/zPV10q

Comment: @n.m. It can't solve my problem while both "文" in Chinese and "ん" in Japanese return false.

Comment: Are you sure? https://ideone.com/T06foh Perhaps your installation is broken. Japanese is of course working too https://ideone.com/tyiugA

Comment: @n.m. In xcode, it printfs `in the default locale, iswalpha(0x6587) = false
in Unicode locale, iswalpha(0x6587) = false`. It's odd.

Comment: Either xcode libraries are broken, or you don't have this exact locale name. What your `locale` command outputs if you type it in the shell?

Comment: @n.m. LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=

Comment: It seems to be a problem of clang and its standard library which doesn't support Unicode properly. https://ideone.com/GTko9a gcc doesn't have this problem, on Linux at least. If you have to use clang, you probably need a third-party Unicode support library.

Comment: Using libstdc++ instead of libc++ may also work for you

Comment: @n.m. libstdc++ does not work, but thanks for your answer. I learned a lot.